# Remove the next element together with the selected one in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am bulk deleting all `div` elements with the id that starts with `leg-`:

```
$('div[id^="leg-"]').remove();
```

I also want to delete `<hr>` element that comes after each div:

```
<div id="leg-1">
    ...
</div>

<hr>
```

There is no event fired that's why, I am unable to select the element like this:

```
$(this).next();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the selection made by jQuery in an intermediate variable like following:

```
var selection = $('div[id^="leg-"]');
selection.next().remove();
selection.remove();
```

Like in the `$(this)` methodology you wanted to use, the variable `selection` now contains a reference to all the `div`s you want to remove. Calling `next()` on that selection returns the immediate sibling, thus the `hr` you want to delete, for each of those `div`.

In general: Wherever you need the same selection in jQuery twice, consider saving it to a variable to speed up your scripts and reduce DOM querying to a minimum.

Comment: That was downvoted for no reason. Good answer, good timing and good advice about caching +1

Comment: Thank you! Others' answers also work very well, but accepted this one because it is understandable and has additional advice :)

Comment: This won't work, because once you apply `remove` on `selection` the elements will be taken out of the DOM, so you won't be able to use `next`.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella well that' why `next` element is deleted first and only then `remove` is applied on `selection`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov if you look at the edit history of this answer, you can notice that it was edited while I was commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You can select next `hr` of div using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) to adding div to jquery selector.

```js
$("div[id^=leg-]").next().addBack().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leg-1">leg-1 text</div>
<hr>
<div>text</div>
<div id="leg-2">leg-2 text</div>
<hr>
<div>text2</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I like yours the most. However, others who read the code, may not be able to understand what `addBack` does the first time without Googling. Thank you very much though. Much deserved upvote

Answer (score 1):

Try this First remove next `<hr>` element the remove selection element

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selection = $('div[id^="leg-"]');
  selection.next('hr').remove();
  selection.remove();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leg-1">
  1
</div>
<hr>
<div id="leg-2">
  2
</div>
<hr>
<div id="">
  3 not leg
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not removing the next element only selecting it.
Please to also add: `$(this).next().remove();` before removing the div element. 
You can use jQuery.each(): https://jsfiddle.net/cdzswdrk/1/

```
// when document ready
    $('div[id^="leg-"]').each(function(){
      var $this= $(this);
      $this.next().remove();
      $this.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Please read question  also want to delete <hr> element that comes after each div:

Comment: I am interested to know why the downvote? is it for the each ?

Comment: @AnkurBhadania, thank you for pointing that. I thought remove() will return the same jQuery object to be chained

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `hr` by combining the jQuery [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) functions in this way:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div[id^="leg-"]').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).next("hr").remove();
    $(v).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leg-1">#leg-1</div>
<hr>
<div id="not-leg-1">#not-leg</div>
<hr>
<div id="leg-2">#leg-2</div>
<hr>
```